# Callback for FirebaseObservable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a simple setup with some code that counts the number of items in my FireBase database.

> This is working but the button is empty until the data is loaded.

Is there a way to hide the button until this is done? Or set a loading state until this is done?

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    likes: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(private angularFire: AngularFire) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getLikes();
    }

    getLikes() {
        this.likes = this.angularFire.database.list('/likes');
    }

}
```

This is my button template

```
<button (click)="onClicked()" class="button">
   {{(likes | async)?.length}}
</button>
```

#### I tried subscribing() to it

```
export class ButtonComponent {

    likes: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(private angularFire: AngularFire) {
        this.angularFire.database.list('/likes').subscribe(
            response => {this.likes = response}
        );
    }

    onClicked() {
        this.likes.push({'like': new Date().toISOString()})
    }
}
```

But that returns the following error:

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>
```

Comment: Can you show the template for the button?

Comment: added to question! thanks for ur response.

Comment: How about adding a conditional to the button, like: `<button (click)="onClicked()" class="button" *ngIf="{{likes | async}}">` does it work? And would it be enough?

Comment: That is working! without the curly brackets offcourse. :) but i'm wondering if there isn't a method that would provide a callback for observables..

Comment: Or remove a class when they exist?

Comment: Humm, interesting, but...what do you mean exactly by "callback for observables"? (Isn't subscribe that? You subscribe a callback to an observable, wouldn't you say?)

Comment: that's what I was thinking! but ( i updated my question ) you can see there i'm getting an error when I try that. thanks for your time!

Comment: You get that error because `this.angularFire.database.list('/likes')` is an `Observable` that "feeds" `any[]` to their subscribers, thus `response` is an `any[]` (and since the `likes` field is an `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`, you get that error).

Comment: Hmh thanks! any idea how I can solve that? I don't really understand why the FBListObservable wont except it?

Comment: But even if that worked, you must notice that the subscribers to the `this.angularFire.database.list('/likes')` won't execute immediately. You'd get the very same delay you are getting now. (Which is expected, since it is an asynchornous operation, in other words, it takes time to complete, the callback -- in this case the subscriber -- won't execute right away, but some time in the future -- sometimes soon, sometimes not so soon.)

Comment: You can put `this.likes = this.angularFire.database.list('/likes');` in the constructor, but it would still be an "empty" observable for sometime (until the connection to the server completes and it sends a reply).

Comment: Aha I understand! thanks so much!